# Kafka Streams: SessionWindowedSerde Vs TimeWindowedSerde. Ambiguous implicit values

Tags: scala, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I keep getting '**ambiguous implicit values**' message in the following code. I tried several things (as can be seen from a couple of lines I've commented out). Any ideas on how to fix this? This is in **Scala**.

```
  def createTopology(conf: Config, properties: Properties): Topology = {
//    implicit val sessionSerde = Serde[WindowedSerdes.SessionWindowedSerde[String]]
//    implicit val produced: Produced[Windowed[String], Long] = Produced.`with`[WindowedSerdes.SessionWindowedSerde[String], Long]
    implicit val produced: Produced[Windowed[String], Long] = Produced.`with`[Windowed[String], Long]
    implicit val consumed: Consumed[String, String] = Consumed.`with`[String, String]

    val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder()
    builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input")
        .groupBy((_, word) => word)
        .windowedBy(SessionWindows.`with`(Duration.ofMillis(60 * 1000)))
        .count()
        .toStream.to("streams-pipe-output")

    builder.build()

  }
```

**Compiler Errors:**

```
Error:(52, 78) ambiguous implicit values:
 both method timeWindowedSerde in object Serdes of type [T](implicit tSerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde[T])org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.WindowedSerdes.TimeWindowedSerde[T]
 and method sessionWindowedSerde in object Serdes of type [T](implicit tSerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde[T])org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.WindowedSerdes.SessionWindowedSerde[T]
 match expected type org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde[org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed[String]]
    implicit val produced: Produced[Windowed[String], Long] = Produced.`with`[Windowed[String], Long]

Error:(52, 78) could not find implicit value for parameter keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde[org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed[String]]
    implicit val produced: Produced[Windowed[String], Long] = Produced.`with`[Windowed[String], Long]

Error:(52, 78) not enough arguments for method with: (implicit keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde[org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed[String]], implicit valueSerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde[Long])org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced[org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed[String],Long].
Unspecified value parameters keySerde, valueSerde.
    implicit val produced: Produced[Windowed[String], Long] = Produced.`with`[Windowed[String], Long]
```

Comment: Can you add the compiler error to the question?

Comment: Added compiler errors as per your request.

Answer (score 0):

I just add some `implicit`s by adding imports and it compiles:

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.{SessionWindows, Windowed}
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.StreamsBuilder
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.kstream.{Consumed, Produced}

import java.time.Duration
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.ImplicitConversions._
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.Serdes
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.Serdes.{Long, String}

def createTopology(conf: Config, properties: Properties): Topology = {
  // here we have two implicits to choose, I pick the sessionWindowedSerde because it was in your code
  // implicit val timeWindowedSerde: Serde[Windowed[String]] = Serdes.timeWindowedSerde[String]
  implicit val sessionSerde: Serde[Windowed[String]] = Serdes.sessionWindowedSerde[String]
  implicit val produced: Produced[Windowed[String], Long] = Produced.`with`[Windowed[String], Long]
  implicit val consumed: Consumed[String, String] = Consumed.`with`[String, String]

  val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder()
  builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input")
    .groupBy((_, word) => word)
    .windowedBy(SessionWindows.`with`(Duration.ofMillis(60 * 1000)))
    .count()
    .toStream.to("streams-pipe-output")

  builder.build()
}
```

If you see an error:

> ambiguous implicit values

it means in your scope defined more than one `implicit`s which satisfying the needed types. For example object `org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.Serdes` has a two implicits:

```
implicit def timeWindowedSerde[T](implicit tSerde: Serde[T]): WindowedSerdes.TimeWindowedSerde[T] =
    new WindowedSerdes.TimeWindowedSerde[T](tSerde)

implicit def sessionWindowedSerde[T](implicit tSerde: Serde[T]): WindowedSerdes.SessionWindowedSerde[T] =
    new WindowedSerdes.SessionWindowedSerde[T](tSerde)
```

where `TimeWindowedSerde` extends `Serdes.WrapperSerde<Windowed<T>>`:

```
static public class TimeWindowedSerde<T> extends Serdes.WrapperSerde<Windowed<T>>
```

and `SessionWindowedSerde` extends `Serdes.WrapperSerde<Windowed<T>>`:

```
static public class SessionWindowedSerde<T> extends Serdes.WrapperSerde<Windowed<T>>
```

both of them extends the same type `Serdes.WrapperSerde<Windowed<T>>`,
and in the line:

```
implicit val produced: Produced[Windowed[String], Long] = Produced.`with`[Windowed[String], Long]
```

according to `with` function signature:

```
def `with`[K, V](implicit keySerde: Serde[K], valueSerde: Serde[V]): ProducedJ[K, V] =
    ProducedJ.`with`(keySerde, valueSerde)
```

we expect some `implicit` value for `Serde[Windowed[String]]` and compiler can't pick one because both of them are `Serde[Windowed[String]]`.

So if you just try to add both of them to the same scope:

```
implicit val timeWindowedSerde: Serde[Windowed[String]] = Serdes.timeWindowedSerde[String]
implicit val sessionSerde: Serde[Windowed[String]] = Serdes.sessionWindowedSerde[String]
```

you will see

```
ambiguous implicit values
```

again.

**Conclusion**: be careful while importing large bunches of `implicits` and the best practice is to import only `implicits` that you needed.